# Finding minimum integer in ArrayList without collections

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find the smallest integer in an `ArrayList` just by using two simple `for` loops. I tried originally with one `for` loop, but it wasn't updating correctly. I haven't learned `collections` yet, so this should be done without using any `collections` code.

This is what I have:

```
public static void printInOrder(ArrayList<Integer> data){

 int minIndex = 0 ;
 for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
   minIndex = i;
   for(int j = i + 1; j < data.size() - 1; j++){
     if(data.get(j) < data.get(minIndex)){
       minIndex = j;}

   }
   System.out.println(data.get(minIndex) + " ");
 }
}//printInOrder
```

My minimum always seems to be the last value in the list, so I tried printing the `data.get(minIndex)` in the first `for` loop to see what happens, and it seems to update it different values, and then finally, the last value. I have no idea why this is happening.

This is what it's printing for example:

`Original list: 
[47, 19, 46, 42, 15, 26, 36, 27, 13, 15, 1, 40, 34, 14, 6, 34, 28, 12, 15, 13]
Print the minimum:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 12 12 12 15 13`

Comment: You don't need double loop.. A single loop should do it as long as you are keeping the current minimum

Comment: Sort the arraylist and return the element at index 0?

Comment: @gtgaxiola, if I tried it with a single loop, what would I compare in my `if` statement? Because I tried that way for a while, but it too wasn't giving me the correct minimum.

Comment: You keep a temporary variable to store the current minimum.

Comment: @sma, oh yes, that would be one way. Would it be possible though to just use one loop as gtgaxiola suggested, just to keep it simple?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Just loop over the collection and keep track of the current minimum.  If the current element is less than the current minimum, set current minimum equal to current element.  At the end of the iteration, current minimum will represent the smallest integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the minimum value in an ArrayList, along with the index number? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995458/how-to-find-the-minimum-value-in-an-arraylist-along-with-the-index-number-jav)

Comment: Your code currently successfully finds the smallest number of the list starting at `i`, for all starting indices `i`. You wanted to find the smallest number of the list starting at `0` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quick solution if you want to avoid using Collections.

```
public static void printInOrder(ArrayList<Integer> data){

    Integer[] array = (Integer[]) data.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(array[0]);

}
```

The smallest integer would always be at index 0 in this case.

Or, if you do want to go through the whole ArrayList using a loop, I'd suggest you store the actual value in a variable instead of the index. Doing so, you get:

```
public static void printInOrder(ArrayList<Integer> data){

    int minInteger = data.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++){
        if(data.get(i) < minInteger) minInteger= data.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(minInteger);

}
```

Comment: `Integer[] array = data.toArray();` doesn't compile.

Comment: My bad, forgot to cast. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do sorting to find the minimum

Here's the code

```
public static void Min(int arr[])
{
   int min = arr[0];
    int i=0;
while(i<arr.length)
 {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min=arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Well , if you are interested in sorting and then find the minimum no problem but the issue was it didn't make a sense and i think it takes up double time to find you a minimum with a single min algo

Comment: Well by analysis, a linear search would have a complexity of O(n), having n iterations worst-case. Using Java's built-in sorting function, it runs at O(n log n), and getting the minimum after that would be O(1) for sure. This, way, I don't think it's as inefficient as it may seem.

Comment: @theguywhodreams Thats one way to look at it, the other is that log2(1024) already works out to 10, so sorting 1024 elements to find the minimum has approximately 10 times the complexity of the linear search. If that is to be considered efficient (enough) or not is highly dependend on the actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
public static int calculateMinIndex(final ArrayList<Integer> data) {
    int minIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; i++) {
        if(data.get(i) > data.get(i+1)) {
            minIndex = i+1;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```